# Generic extension method with custom return type

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write an extension method for two entities.

First find the type of object, then do an `inner join` with another table.

If it's type A then `Join` must be with B. If it's type B then join with A.
But I got stuck on the `Join` condition.

```
public static C GetAllInfo<T>(this IQueryable<T> objCust)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
    {
        //prepare the Object based on the Type 
        var objCastReg = objCust as IQueryable<B>;
        //how to write join here   ?????
        var  objUsermaster=objCastReg.GroupJoin(A,um=>um.UserId,r=>r.)

       //Build the Class object  from two retrieved objects.
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
    {
        var objCast = objCust as IQueryable<A>;
    }
    return null;
}

public class C
{
    public A A{ get; set; }

    public B B{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'd say this isn't really generic since you only have two classes and you want to do different things with each of them. I'd just go for writing two separate methods.

Comment: @Chris Can we Write join condition inside extension method without passing second entity as argument. still running on sand

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you shouldn't use generics at all. Generics are for when your generic method *does not need to know* the type. A generic type parameter signals that this method can work with any concrete type whatsoever.

Maybe you should just have two special-cased method for both cases here. That makes all the casting and complexity go away.

But if you insist on a generic method, here is how to do it. First create the special-case method I was speaking of.

```
public static C GetAllInfo(this IQueryable<A> objCust); //implement this
public static C GetAllInfo(this IQueryable<B> objCust); //implement this
```

Then delegate to them:

```
public static C GetAllInfo<T>(this IQueryable<T> objCust)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(B))
    {
        return GetAllInfo((IQueryable<B>)objCust); //call to specialized impl.
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(A))
    {
        return GetAllInfo((IQueryable<A>)objCust); //call to specialized impl.
    }
    //fail
}
```

Comment: agree with you on this, but still i cant write the join inside extension method , as class name is not allowed for joining. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What do you mean, "class name not allowed for joining"? I added code.

Comment: i mean, with my code formal parameter `objCust.GroupJoin( A`[A is not allowed there as it represent the Class].

Comment: `return GetAllInfo<B>((IQueryable<B>)objCust);` won't call a non-generic method. I think you mean `return GetAllInfo((IQueryable<B>)objCust);` (and similarly for `A`)

Comment: @joshua if you have follow up questions you can ask them here and I'll answer. Is the problem solved for you?

Comment: One should be able to call the generic method without specifying `T`, because it can be inferred from the `objCust` parameter... but this isn't possible in this case because overload resolution would always call the non-generic methods directly because they are public and have the same name.